# MySQL calculate number of items FROM an INNER relationship

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a set of collections from a table and I can not figure out how I can calculate the number of likes from the the related table 'like_collections' using LEFT JOIN syntax.

As you can see in the query, for each **collection_id** I need to get the number of users that like such collection.

I know I can merely use `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes_collections WHERE collection_id=cn.id) as n_likes` but want to know if it possible using the below query.

```
SELECT  cn.id,
        cn.name,
        cn.description,
        u.avatar,
        u.username,
        COUNT(lc.id) as n_likes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM collection_items WHERE collection_id=cn.id) as n_items
FROM collection_names as cn 
INNER JOIN users as u ON u.ID=cn.user_id 
LEFT JOIN likes_collections as lc ON lc.collection_id=cn.id
WHERE cn.public=1
GROUP BY lc.collection_id
ORDER BY cn.published_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `n_likes`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a `LEFT JOIN`, you shouldn't use a column in the child table in the `GROUP BY`. This is because columns from that table will all be `NULL` when there are no matches for the row in the master table, and it will group all those unmatched rows together. So you should `GROUP BY cn.id` rather than `GROUP BY lc.collection_id`.

And instead of the correlated subquery, you can join with a subquery that calculates the number of items grouped by collection ID.

```
SELECT  cn.id,
        cn.name,
        cn.description,
        u.avatar,
        u.username,
        COUNT(lc.id) as n_likes,
        n_items
FROM collection_names as cn 
INNER JOIN users as u ON u.ID=cn.user_id 
LEFT JOIN likes_collections as lc ON lc.collection_id=cn.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT collection_id, COUNT(*) AS n_items
           FROM collection_items
           GROUP BY collection_id) AS ci ON ci.collection_id = cn.id
WHERE cn.public=1
GROUP BY cn.id
ORDER BY cn.published_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```